# Days remaining to return before American visa expires

Tags: visas, usa

We want to travel to the US for two weeks in the middle of July for a holiday and return at the end of July.  Our visa expires in the middle of August will we be able to get into the US?

Comment: Can you explain more? What citizen are you? Where are you travelling from? The more information, the more useful it'll be!

Comment: as long as your visa expires after you leave the US territory, it should be fine. But your question is not clear. By "return" you mean leaving the US for your home country or return to the US?

Comment: If you give more details, others might be able to provide a detailed answer but in principle a visa is valid until its expiration date. In the US, the period of stay might even extend beyond the validity of the visa, which need only be valid on the day of entry. Generally, you do however need a passport that is valid for six months after the end of your intended stay (you can even use another passport together with a visa apposed in an expired passport but you need a passport that will be valid long enough).

Comment: @Vince: A U.S. visa is only for entering the U.S., period. Once you enter the U.S., the visa is irrelevant. It does not determine how long you can stay.

Comment: @Janet: As long as you have a valid U.S. visa, you can apply to enter the U.S. It could be the day before it expires; it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you all. our visas are valid till mid-August but we want to visit the Us in July and return by the end of July.